# NextJS- Update URL on SSR fetch request is done

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

How can I render a dynamic router component and not changing the URL?

I have **SearchInput** component where I'm using it in multiple places in the project

```
const SearchInput = (props) =>{
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const submit = () =>{
       //How can I render the dynamic component and when the SSR fetch request is done update the URL

        const router = useRouter();
        return router.push(`/search/${value}`);  //this way is chaning the URL :(
    }
    return (
        <>
          <input value={value} onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)} />  
          <button onClick={}>Search</button>
        </>
    )
}
export default SearchInput;
```

This is the nested SSR dynamic router looks like this

**pages/search/[searchValue].js**

```
export const search = async (searchValue) => {
    //this request retun a URL that needs to be shown in the browser
    //How can I change the URL here?

   const users = await axios.post(`/API/search`, {search: searchValue}).then(({data}) => {
            return data
        })
    return users
}
const SearchResult = ({downloads}) =>{

    return (
        <>
            <SearchInput />
            <section>
             {downloads.map((row)=>{
                        return <h1>{row.title}</h1>
                    })}
            </section>
           
        </>
    )
}
export default SearchResult;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
     const { searchValue } = context.query;
    const res = await search(searchValue);
    return {
        props: {
            downloads: res,
            url: res.link
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm using Server Side Rendering so I'm wondering how can I fetch the request first then change the URL?

The current approach is working but it changes the URL first then rendering the nested component. What I want to achieve is to render the SSR component first and fetch the request then changing the URL. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
const SearchInput = () =>{
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <>
          <input value={value} onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)} />  
          <button onClick={()=> router.push(`/search/${value}`)}>Search</button>
        </>
    )
}
export default SearchInput;
```

fetch dynamic route :

```
const SearchResult = ({searchData}) =>{

    return (
        <>
            <SearchInput />
            <section>
             {searchData.map((row)=>{
                        return <h1>{row.title}</h1>
                    })}
            </section>
           
        </>
    )
}


export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
     const { searchValue } = context.query;
    const search = await axios.post(`/API/search`, {search: searchValue})
    \\ you can use fetch 
    const searchData = await search.json();
    return {
        props: {
            searchData
        }
    }
}
export default SearchResult;
```